# Function for create a cumulative index of returns

Tags: r, finance

Im trying to code a function to calculate the cumulative index returns where calculations would be current observation / first observation in an xts object.
Here's a sample of my code:

```
    cumret <- function(x){
      cum <- rep(0,nrow(x))
      for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
        cum[i,] <-x[i,]/x[1,]
      }
      cumret <- cum
      return(cumret)
    }
```

Then when a tried it, shows this error:
"incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"

As input data, I used e.g.

```
Prices <- c(23,23.5,24,24.3,24.6,25)
```

I want to create a vector of cumulative returns, `Cum.Ret <- Price[i,] / as.numeric(Prices[1,])`

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example and expecteed output

Comment: Of course: For example the normalize returns of the sp500 during a time window would begin with 1 and end with the total cumulative return. Expected output would be a time series of these cumulative returns.

Comment: According to `R` tag, the minimal reproducible example expected is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Do you need `cumsum(Prices/Prices[1])`

Comment: Here is: Prices <- c(23,23.5,24,24.3,24.6,25) 
I want to create a vector of cmulative Returns:
Cum.Ret <- Price[i,] / as.numeric(Prices[1,])

Comment: Comments are not ideal for pasting examples. Please edit your original question.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to divide by the first element and then take the `cumsum`

```
cumsum(Prices/Prices[1])
```

#### data

```
Prices <- c(23,23.5,24,24.3,24.6,25)
```

Comment: The problem is that this will no returns a time series of cumulative returns, only total return. Let me be more suscint, I try to reproduce a time series for the value of 1 $dollar for a given set of prices.

Comment: @AlanVazquez  Not clear from the comments.  You provided an example and I try to use that example to create the expected